# template match with below XPATH means

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Can anyone tell me the meaning of the below template match

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="*(*)">
```

What i guessed is , the first template match will be applied for all the element nodes which dont have any child elements

and second match applies for the elements with child elements
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is used to match any element. Where you have square brackets, this represents a condition to be checked on that element. In this case `not(*)` is checking that there are no child elements.

Therefore `<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">` will match elements that have no child elements. Thus it it would match this (as `Bob` is a text node, not an element)

```
<Name>Bob</Name>
```

And this (as `type` is an attribute, not an element).

```
<Name type="A" />
```

But it would not match this (as `Name` has the child element `FirstName`)

```
<Name><FirstName>Bob</FirstName></Name>
```

The second pattern `<xsl:template match="*(*)">` is not actually valid syntax.

If you were trying to match elements which did have child elements, you would do this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
```

Comment: thx Tim :)
may be for the second template match can we have like this <xsl:template match = *[*] >   to match all the elements whcih have child elements for it

Comment: To match elements with child elements do `<xsl:template match="*[*]">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
```

It means element that doesn't have any element under it.

```
<xsl:template match="*(*)">
```

This looks to be syntactically wrong. Because you should use `[]` there. Then it would mean select any element that has element(s) under it.

Here element is a tag `<tag>` not text node or attribute. Hope it answers.